# Cannot find local variable on click, debugger opens Looper.java, app dies

Tags: java, android, loops, android-viewpager

I'm trying to learn how to make a viewPager with dots that show the progress, basically those welcome screens, and I'm following a tutorial. It's well annotated and I seem to get what is happening, however when I click my "next" button the app dies.

I'm attaching the code bellow, along with a screenshot of the error I get in the debugger. Hopefully somebody would be able to help. I've returned everything as it was in the tutorial to make sure it's not my "creative input" that is messing but still it crashes. The "skip" button works just fine:

```
myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
           int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the "Fatal exception" I'm getting:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.android.signs, PID: 31291
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>           at com.example.android.signs.WelcomeActivity.addBottomDots(WelcomeActivity.java:99)
>           at com.example.android.signs.WelcomeActivity.access$400(WelcomeActivity.java:24)
>           at com.example.android.signs.WelcomeActivity$2.onPageSelected(WelcomeActivity.java:123)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1947)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:686)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:670)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
>           at com.example.android.signs.WelcomeActivity$1.onClick(WelcomeActivity.java:80)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6305)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24840)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   Application terminated.

^ Here I always have hope it will just step over and move on to the next page

^ When I step over I get a "Cannot find local variable 'btnNext'", takes me to looper and gets stuck. Found some topics of people turning off testCoverage in gradle but that wasn't there, still added it and set it to "false" but the error stayed the same.

Also adding the repository: https://github.com/simplydikka/traffic.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);
        int index = currentPage;
        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[0]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[0]);
    }
```

The problem is where you are using the current page (which is increasing) as an index for an array which is not increasing. The index of the dot array will always be 0 so just use 0. I was able to make it all the way to the home screen, I think, hard to tell when I cant read anything. I dont think you even need the array for the dots.

Comment: Oooooh my god, that fixed it, thank you so much. The debugger was stopping soearly on so I didn't even look for the issue lower. Jesus. Thank you!